# Find and validate immediate neighbors of the given source node of a 2D matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, adjacency-matrix

I am working on a Javascript project for the pathfinding visualiser where I am having difficulty in finding and validating the immediate neighbours of a source node in a 2D Matrix.

**Problem Statement**: Given a sorted 4X3 2D matrix, let's say array=[{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}] 
in which we have to find immediate neighbours (LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN) of a given number. It's easy to calculate the **left** or **right** just by adding or subtract 1 and add or subtract 4 for the **bottom** or **up**,  But for the elements at extreme end.

- How do we validate that number returned is a neighbour or not?*

Example: **neighbour**(5) = [ 1,6,9 ] *(4 isn't a neighbour)*

also 
         **neighbour**(7) = [ 3,6,8,11]

```
         left = source -1 ;
         right = source +1 ;
         top = source - 4 ;
         bottom = source +4;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate valid list of neigbours, you have to check for border crossing

```
col = (source - 1) % width    
if (col > 0)
   left = source - 1
if (col < width - 1)
   right = source + 1 
line = (source - 1) / width     
if (line > 0)
   top = source  - width 
if (line < height - 1)
   bottom = source + width
```